# 2 messages from django views

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, view, message

I want to return two messages from a django view. For example, after I created some object (message:"object was created") and after I create related object("related object was created"). I want to display these messages on current webpage. I think I need to use jQuery and Ajax post request (Ajax request + return of view, which creates object from request) and show div's after request is completed, what do you think about this?

Comment: simple answer to question asked is... `I think it will work`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To return a message via ajax, use `alert`. I would do something like this:

```
def view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        //whatever you need to do
    else:
        //regular POST request
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('div#ajax-div').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"/ajax-url/",
  success: function(data){alert('Object was created!');}
  error: function(){alert("Error");}
});
}
```

template:

```
<div id='ajax-div'>
  <a href='{% url ajax-url %}'>Click here for Message</a>
</div>
```

url:

```
url(r'^ajax-url/$', 'views.view', name='ajax_url'),
```

Comment: thanks, i will try this later, i think it will be simple, because i  will want to do like this, but with form and form.errors :) But i have also one problem, i need to return it from class Exp(object), witch contains few big methods :O I used this methods for some actions and want to print progress on web-page ;(